# Regarding the use of " and thereby"

Tags: word-usage

I am a bit confused regarding the use of " and thereby " in academic English, For example in the following sentence:

> Example: The Taylor cone became unstable for a period of time, and thereby spraying and dripping of the solution occurred.

I checked well-known dictionaries such as Longman and Cambridge, when " thereby" is used, it is commonly followed by a "gerund". Thus, I want to know whether the structure I have used in my example above is correct or not since it is " ..., and thereby X occurred."

Comment: Maybe, _therefore should replace thereby_ in the given sentence.

Comment: **thereby** = by it; **thereto** = to it; **therewith** = with it, etc. Your sentence does not make sense with "thereby".

Comment: Grammatically the sentence is OK, but *thereby* seems to be a wrong word for the intended meaning. 'X and thereby Y' means that X and Y are two aspects of the **same** event. If the cone becoming unstable is the cause of spraying etc., but distinct from it, then *therefore* or *as a result* is more appropriate than *thereby*. Or perhaps one could say that the cone became unstable and thereby caused spraying etc.

Comment: I did not get my answer! you know "thereby" is used commonly when it is intended to say one even is the result of another one. For example form Cambridge dictionary: